# image upload to ftp with arrays php

Tags: php, arrays, file-upload, ftp

I would like to try to upload multiple images to a folder on my FTP. I tried already uploading to my database, and that worked with my code. It's the first time I'm writing code to upload a file to the FTP.

**In my config.php:**

```
$ftp_server = "**";
$ftp_username = "**";
$ftp_password= "**";
$connect = mysql_connect($ftp_server, $ftp_username, $ftp_password)
or die ("Hey, check your server connection.");
```

**Code to upload file:**

```
include_once '..includes/config.php';
$files = array();
$fdata = $_FILES['image'];

if (is_array($fdata['name'])) {
    for($i=0;$i<count($fdata['name']);$i++) {
        $files[] = array(
            'name' => $fdata['name'][$i],
            'tmp_name' => $fdata['tmp_name'][$i]
        );
    }
} else $files[] = $fdata;

foreach($files as $file) {
    $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
    $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_username, $ftp_password);

    ftp_put($conn_id, "public_html/img/" . $file['name'],$file['tmp_name']),FTP_BINARY);
    print_r($files['tmp_name']);
}
```

When I try to print my `$files['tmp_name']`, I get an blanc page and the file isn't uploaded to my FTP. Can somebody help me?

Thanks.

Comment: The problem with your print_r expression is the variable name. You want print_r($file['tmp_name'])

Comment: You shouldn't use mysql_* functions switch to mysqli for better security and performance.

Comment: What does `var_dump($files);` give you right before the `foreach`?

Comment: @jeroen array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(15) "favicon - 5.png" ["tmp_name"]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpWfBuw9" } }

Comment: Does it work if you use a file with a name that does not contain spaces?

Comment: No. But before, I've tried adding the image name in the database, and that worked. Could there be something wrong with my code in the foreach?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add an index to your files assignation, like this:

```
$files[$i] = array(
        'name' => $fdata['name'][$i],
        'tmp_name' => $fdata['tmp_name'][$i]
    );
```

Then you would get tmp_name of whatever index you want

```
$files[$index]["tmp_name"];
```